# Multiple User Inputs with Try Catch InputMismatchException

Tags: java, try-catch

Okay so I am trying to catch these user inputs which I can do but the problem is when I catch it, it doesn't return to the input the user mistyped(InputMismatchException) on but instead it will go back to the start of the loop. Lets say If the user makes an error on the second input, it will return to the first input which the user correctly typed. I've just left it basic and removed my attempt at it.

```
    public class TestRefuseTruck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxBins;
        int rate;
        int weight;
        int count = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of bins the truck can collect: ");
            maxBins = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the cost per kilo:");
            rate = in.nextInt();
            RefuseTruck r = new RefuseTruck(maxBins, rate);
            while (count < maxBins) {
                System.out.println("Enter the weight for bin " + (count + 1));
                weight = in.nextInt();
                if (r.collectBin(weight) == true) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            r.printStats();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Input.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `try-catch` ?

Comment: where is your `RefuseTruck` class?

Comment: @RajS.Rusia it's irrelevant. I'm only trying to catch inputmismatch's in the test class and handle it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated

Keep each input in a separate while-loop until the input is correct:

```
int maxBins = 0;
int rate = 0;
int weight = 0;
int count = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(maxBins == 0){
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of bins the truck can collect: ");
        maxBins = in.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Input.");
    }
}
while(rate == 0){
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the cost per kilo:");
        rate = in.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Input.");
    }
}
RefuseTruck r = new RefuseTruck(maxBins, rate);
while (count < maxBins) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the weight for bin " + (count + 1));
        weight = in.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Input.");
        continue;
    }
    if (r.collectBin(weight) == true) {
        count++;
    }
}
r.printStats();
```

Keep in mind this regards "0" as an invalid input (loop is executed again).

Comment: I've updated my question since it was probably a bit vague but that part was working fine but it's just if the user makes an error on the second it will go back to the first input, I'm not sure how to fix that.